# regular expressions and xpath query

Tags: php, html, regex, xpath

I have the following code

```
        <?php
        $doc = new DOMDocument;
        $doc->loadhtml('<html>
                       <head> 
                        <title>bar , this is an example</title> 
                       </head> 
                       <body> 
                       <h1>latest news</h1>
                       foo <strong>bar</strong> 
                      <i>foobar</i>
                       </body>
                       </html>');


        $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
        foreach($xpath->query('//*[contains(child::text(),"bar")]') as $e) {
              echo $e->tagName, "\n";
        }
```

Prints

```
       title
       strong
       i
```

this code finds any HTML element that contains the word "bar" and it matches words that has "bar" like "foobar" I want to change the query to match only the word "bar" without any prefix or postfix

I think it can be solved by changing the query to search for every "bar" that has not got a letter after or before or has a space after or before

this code from a past question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231606/how-to-figure-out-the-location-of-a-keyword-in-an-html-document) by [VolkerK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4833/volkerk)

Thanks

Comment: Reference: [Using regex to filter attributes in xpath with php](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6823032/367456) (Jul 2011),

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following XPath Query

```
$xpath->query("//*[text()='bar']");
```

or

```
$xpath->query("//*[.='bar']");
```

Note using the "//" will slow things down, the bigger you XML file is.

Comment: Thanks but this does not work, it prints: "strong" whilst it should prints "strong" and "title" because the word "bar" is in the title as well

Comment: I thought you just wanted to match just "bar" now I see you want it to match "bar" or "this bar now" but *not* "this foobar now".

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for just "bar" with XPath 1.0 then you'll have to use a combo of functions, there are no regular expressions in XPath 1.0.

```
$xpath->query("//*[
                starts-with(., 'bar') or 
                contains(., ' bar ') or  
                ('bar' = substring(.,string-length(.)-string-length('bar')+1))
              ]");
```

Basically this is saying locate strings that `start-with` 'bar' or `contains` ' bar ' (notice the spaces before and after) or `ends-with` 'bar' (notice that ends-with is an XPath 2.0 function, so I substituted code which emulates that function from a previous [Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402211/how-to-use-xpath-function-in-a-xpathexpression-instance-programatically).)

if the contains ' bar ' is not enough, because you may have `"one bar, over"` or `"This bar. That bar."` where you may have other punctuation after the `'bar'`. You could try this `contains` instead:

```
contains(translate(., '.,[]', ' '), ' bar ') or
```

That translates any `'.,[]'` to a `' '` (single space)... so `"one bar, over"` becomes `"one bar  over"`, thus would match `" bar "` as expected.