# Using regex to filter attributes in xpath with php

Tags: php, regex, xpath

I am trying to filter html tables with regex matching their id attribute. What am i doing wrong? Code i am trying to implement:

```
        $this->xpath = new DOMXPath($this->dom); 
            $this->xpath->registerNamespace("php", "http://php.net/xpath");
            $this->xpath->registerPHPFunctions();
        foreach($xpath->query("//table[php:function('preg_match', '/post\d+/', @id)]") as $key => $row)
    {

}
```

Error that i get: preg_match expects second param to be a string, array given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An attribute is still a complex element according to DOM (has a namespace etc.). Use:

```
//table[php:function('preg_match', '/post\d+/', string(@id))]
```

Now, we need a boolean return, so:

```
function booleanPregMatch($match,$string){
    return preg_match($match,$string)>0;
}
$xpath->registerPHPFunctions();
foreach($xpath->query("//table[@id and php:function('booleanPregMatch', '/post\d+/', string(@id))]") as $key => $row){
     echo $row->ownerDocument->saveXML($row);
}
```

BTW: for more complex issues, you can of course sneakily check what's happening with this:

```
//table[php:function('var_dump',@id)]
```

It's a shame we don't have XPATH 2.0 functions available, but if you can handle this requirement with a more unreliable `starts-with`, I'd always prefer that over importing PHP functions.

Comment: No errors, but the preg_match is not filtering.If i use this foreach($xpath->query("//table[@id]") as $key => $row) i get 16 tables, but the above query gives 68 tables!!

Comment: I did a print_r and got some domObject stuff. that seems to be taken care of with string(@id), but the preg_match is running true even when it should not!

Comment: Ah, you're right, a proper boolean is required. I'll edit it in.

Comment: I tried this re:test(src, pattern, flags) but get evaluate errors! so there is no way i can do a regex match on attributes!!

Comment: I tried php:functionBool and php:functionBoolean neither works!

Comment: Boolean is required btw, as I _believe_ casting goes like this: `(1) PHP => (int)0 (2) DOM => (string)"0" (3) DOM => (string)"0" !== false`

Comment: php:function('booleanPregMatch' gives unknown handler!

Comment: @sam: calm down. See the function I put _above_ there? Put it in.

Comment: No need for an additional function at all, see my edited answer. `preg_match` returns either FALSE (regex error), 0 (not found) or 1 (found). xpath can properly handle that return value.

Comment: exactly, but it runs true on all tables!

Comment: @hakre: Hmmm, that last edit might be more elegant indeed, I'd keep the `[@id and...` in front of it though, saves needless functioncalls. Put that in and you'll get my vote.

Comment: @sam: compare against `1 = php:function('preg_match', ...`, returns only those tables that preg_match the id.

Comment: Ok the issue is with preg_match, preg_match returns int, not boolean!

Comment: @Wrikken, I already wondered earlier if this is actually needed, I will run a test. *Edit:* Here too, do the check for `@id` to prevent as you already suggested.

Comment: `string(@id)` runs here on all tables, regardless of whether they have an `id` attribute or not.

Comment: @Wrikken, about "XPath2 (...) always prefer that over importing PHP functions". *Can you compare performance in this tipical case?* As far as I know, XSLT1 (running with [LibXML2](http://xmlsoft.org/libxslt/) like PHP) is faster than any XSLT2 parser (ex. [Saxon/C](http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/index.xml)), and the use of the PHP functions (by `registerPHPFunctions`) causes no overhead (rather it improves reuse!)... Do you agree my assumptions? (but they need some benchmarking) or there are another assumptions, like to reuse the same XSLT in a non-PHP context?

Comment: @PeterKrauss: as of yet, we have no 'native XPath2' in PHP AFAIK, so it's hard to test actual performance. I would assume it depends very much on the functionality required, and the documents involved. Keep in mind that in essence ever node / set that matches before the 'external' functions has to be converted to something PHP can do something with & back again to the resultset, which might be considerable overhead on large collections, but negligible on smaller sets, so test performance for typical documents & use cases in both solutions when available if it's a bottleneck.

Answer (score 2):

> What am i doing wrong?

The xpath expression `@id` (second parameter) returns an array but `preg_match` expects a string.

Convert it to string first: `string(@id)`.

Next to that you need to actually compare the output to 1 as `preg_match` returns `1` when found:

```
foreach($xpath->query("//table[@id and 1 = php:function('preg_match', '/post\d+/', string(@id))]") as $key => $row)
{
    var_dump($key, $row, $row->ownerDocument->saveXml($row));
}
```

**Explanation/What happens here?:**

A xpath expression will by default return a node-list (more precisely node-set). If you map a PHP function onto such expressions these sets are represented in form of an array. You can easily tests that by using `var_dump`:

```
$xpath->query("php:function('var_dump', //table)");

array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(DOMElement)#3 (0) {
  }
}
```

Same for the xpath expression `@id` in the context of each table element:

```
$xpath->query("//table[php:function('var_dump', @id)]");

array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(DOMAttr)#3 (0) {
  }
}
```

You can change that into a string typed result by making use of the [xpath `string` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-String-Functions):

> A node-set is converted to a string by returning the string-value of the node in the node-set that is first in document order. If the node-set is empty, an empty string is returned.

```
$xpath->query("//table[php:function('var_dump', string(@id))]");

string(4) "test"
```

(the table has `id="test"`)