# preg_replace only enclosing tag

Tags: php, regex

I have an html code like below(just a part of it)

```
<p>
  <strong>
    <div align="center">
      <a onclick="return hs.expand(this)" href="http://example.com/somesome.png">
        <img title="some-bla-bla-text" src="http://example.com/somesome.png" 
             alt="some-bla-bla-text" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </strong><br />
  <strong>
    <div align="center">...
```

and want to strip it out as

```
<p>
  <strong>
    <div align="center">
      <img title="some-bla-bla-text" alt="some-bla-bla-text" />
    </div>
  </strong><br />
  <strong>
    <div align="center">...
```

How can I remove `<a onclick="return hs.expand(this)" href="http://example.com/somesome.png">` and its closing tag `</a>` part of this string?

A regex to match between `<a onclick="return hs.expand(this)"....>` and `</a>` would be very helpful I think

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best methods to parse HTML with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html-with-php)

Comment: Related: [Using regex to filter attributes in xpath with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823032/using-regex-to-filter-attributes-in-xpath-with-php/6823087)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do what you want with regexes, but you need to provide more details.  Do you want to remove *all* anchor elements, replacing them with whatever was inside them?  Or only those that contain IMG tags?  Here's a regex that peels off only those anchor tags whose first attribute is `onclick`:

```
$s= preg_replace('~\s*<a\s+onclick="[^"]*"[^>]*>((?:(?!</a>).)*)</a>\s*~is', '$1', $s);
```

**[see a demo on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/QlIuM)**

---

**EDIT:** This regex will match an anchor element with an `onclick` attribute (not necessarily first).

```
'~\s*<a[^>]*\s+onclick="[^"]*"[^>]*>((?:(?!</a>).)*)</a>\s*~is'
```

**[demo](http://ideone.com/AQdQf)**

Comment: Yes I wanted "a regex that peels off only those anchor tags whose attribute is onclick(not first but must have)" thanks a lot. Can you make some changes to match these?

Answer (score 4):

Regex isn't powerful enough to do this very well since HTML is not a regular language. It might work in some cases, but then it will be very fragile code that could break when given a different, perfectly valid HTML input. You should look into [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). It allows you to parse HTML easily.

Comment: That's more a comment than an answer.

Comment: It answers his question perfectly. He can "`remove ... and it's closing tag <a/>`" using `DOMDocument`.

Comment: @PaulPRO I tried DOMDocument but can't find the right solution, maybe you can 'answer' the question which is better a 'comment'

Comment: @PaulPRO: I'm not objecting that what you wrote is generally right, but it's not answering the question in specific. A simple example code how to do that with DomDocument should not be asked too much, or is it?

Comment: @rasputin, since I can't see the code around it, and your anchor tag has no id attribute, I can't come up with a concrete way that will for sure work with all your html unless you want it to remove *all* `<a>` tags in the whole document.

Comment: @PaulPRO, yes the actual problem is that, it has no id, name, attribure or something else. I think solution must be done with regex. Maybe someone can give us a regex to match between `<a onclick="return hs.expand(this)"(*?)>` and `</a>

Comment: @rasputin If you knew the layout of the whole document you could easily navigate to it and remove it. If you know that `<a onclick="return hs.expand(this)" href="http://example.com/somesome.png">` will never change, and there is only one copy of it in the document then you can use regex easily enough. Just do something like `preg_replace('/<a onclick="return hs.expand\(this\)" href="http:\/\/example\.com\/somesome\.png">(.*?)<\/a>/', '$1');` That regex will work in this very specific situation.

Answer (score 2):

with some testing and tweaking you might be able to get something like the following to work

```
$html = preg_replace('/\<a[^>]*\>((?!\<\/a\>).)*\<\/a\>/i', '\1', $html);
```

it basically says, find an open a tag, then find everything up to the next closing a tag