# xpath query with regex

Tags: php, regex, xpath

it's very simple there is an HTML file and there is a div with variable id like that

```
<div id="abc_1"><div>
```

the integer part of the id is variable so it could be abc_892, abc_553 ...etc

what is the best query to get that ?

Comment: Reference: [Using regex to filter attributes in xpath with php](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6823032/367456) (Jul 2011)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
//div[starts-with(@id, "abc_")]
```

Answer (score 2):

**The currently accepted answer selects such unwanted elements as:**

```
<div id="abc_xyz"/>
```

But only such `div` elements must be accepted, whose `id` not only starts with `"abc_"` but the substring following the `_` is a representation of an integer.

**Use this XPath expression**:

```
//div
   [@id[starts-with(., 'abc_') 
      and 
        floor(substring-after(.,'_')) 
       = 
        number(substring-after(.,'_')) 
       ]
   ]
```

This selects any `div` element that has an `id` attribute whose string value starts with the string `"abc_"` and the substring after the `-` is a valid representation of an integer.

**Explanation**:

Here we are using the fact that in XPath 1.0 this XPath expression:

```
floor($x) = number($x)
```

evaluates to `true()` exactly when `$x` is an integer.

**This can be proven easily:**

1. If `$x` is an integer the above expression evaluates to `true()` by definition.
2. If the above expression evaluates to `true()`, this means that neither of the two sides of the equality are `NaN`, because by definition `NaN` isn't equal to any value (including itself). But then this means that `$x` is a number (`number($x)` isnt `NaN`) and by definition, a number `$x` that is equal to the integer `floor($x)` is an integer.

**Alternative solution**:

```
//div
   [@id[starts-with(., 'abc_') 
      and 
        'abc_' = translate(., '0123456789', '')
       ]
   ]
```

Comment: could you explain why that works? I'm not very familiar with xpath, so I'm guessing floor() will return a value that is never equal to itself, like sql's ternary logic(eg, `null = null` in sql is always false)? thanks.

Comment: @chris: Done. BTW there was a slight inaccuracy in the expression and this is fixed now.

Comment: @chris: You are welcome. Yes, XPath (even 1.0) is a very powerful language and tool for elegant solutions.

Comment: Well, as I said I think that additional check is probably unnecessary, but I'm sure it'll probably be useful to some. Just out of curiosity though, would `//div[@id[translate(.,'0123456789','') = 'abc_']]` not be faster?

Comment: @Flynn1179: Both ways are O(N) -- and if one is faster this would depend on implementation. An XPath engine optimizer may or may not recognize and optimize a particular expression. I prefer `floor($x) = $x` because this is more readable and understandable and translates nicely into "type-checking".