# php xpath query with contains and regex

Tags: php, regex, xpath

Right now I have a xpath search function that looks like this:

```
$paragraph = $xmldoc->xpath("//p[contains(., '$wordsearch')]");
```

I was wondering if it is possible to let `$wordsearch` be a regular expression, so that my search looked something like this:

```
$paragraph = $xmldoc->xpath("//p[contains(., '$regularExpression')]");
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's [not supported](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405060/can-i-use-a-regex-in-an-xpath-expression), because in PHP the underlying library [only implements XPath 1.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085632/will-xpath-2-0-and-or-xslt-2-0-be-implemented-in-php).

Comment: erg, php is letting me down

Comment: you can filter the return array with the regex instead.

Comment: Reference: [Using regex to filter attributes in xpath with php](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6823032/367456) (Jul 2011)

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the array with the regex instead:

```
$paragraph = array_filter(
    $xmldoc->xpath("//p"), 
    function ($p) use ($regularExpression) {
        return preg_match($regularExpression, $p);
    }
);
```

See [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter).