# Get dom elements with particular string in the attribute

Tags: php, xpath

I am trying to use `DOMXPath` to find all attributes that contain this value `{{xxx}}` (where `xxx` can be anything).

This is what I am currently using, but it isn't working. Nor am I getting any errors saying that is an invalid query.

```
foreach($docx->query('//*[*="*{{*}}*"]') as $node){
    // Do some stuff
}
```

I am trying to find items that might look like (but not limited to) the following:

```
<a href="/path/{{value}}">Link</a>
<p class="{{classes}}"></p>
```

Is there any way to get items that look like this using `DOMXPath::query()`?

Comment: [Using regex to filter attributes in xpath with php](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6823032/367456) (Jul 2011)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XPath 2.0 has a [`matches()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-matches) function that lets you use regular expressions. In 1.0 though, which is what `DOMXPath` uses, your best bet would probably be something like:

```
//*[contains(@*,"{{") and contains(@*,"}}")]
```

Note this would still match cases where `}}` precedes `{{` or where there's nothing between those two, so you'd probably want to double-check the results once you get them.

Comment: That almost worked, I had to modify it to look like this: `//*[*=contains(., "{{") and *=contains(., "}}")]`

Comment: @lafor What would you want `.*`  to mean if it were a valid expression? Also, the XPath 1.0 expression in your answer is not really precise. Currently, it would match elements where `{{` and `}}` occur in separate attributes. Use `//*[@*[contains(.,'{{') and contains(.,'}}')]]`.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn, the XPath expression you showed doesn't look at attributes at all. And comparing `* = contains(...)` really doesn't make sense: It's like saying "the current node has child elements whose text value is 'false'". It certainly doesn't do what you asked for in your question.

Comment: @MathiasMüller Are you sure it does match `{{` and `}}` in separate attributes? Because I wasn't so I actually checked it does *not*.

Comment: You are right, but the reason is very different. Try running `//*[contains(@*,"}}")]` against this tiny document: `<root a="{{" b="{{}}"/>`. Guess the result before checking. Then use `<root a="{{}}" b="}}"/>`. In other words, it appears that your solution does not work when there are unclosed opening curly braces, as in `<root a="{{" b="{{}}"/>`. But I admit that this is quite peculiar.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I will have to look into it more, but the current solution got me nodes I was looking for, but maybe my doc wasn't complex enough.